# ¿Cómo agrego varios sources a un elemento de audio con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Teniendo el siguiente ejemplo para agregar un archivo `AudioTest_(1).mp3` a un **elemento de audio** [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), quiero agregar además el archivo `AudioTest_(1).ogg` en caso de que no exista códec para reproducir el primero.

```js
var audioel = document.getElementById('audioElem');
if (audioel !== null) {
  audioel.setAttribute('src', 'http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).mp3');
}
```

```html
<audio id="audioElem" autoplay>
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Normalmente se tendrían varios elementos `source` y el navegador elegiría automáticamente el primero del que tenga los códecs para reproducirlo, pero no sé si es posible hacerlo mediante **Javascript Únicamente** o si existe alguna otra manera de cargar el archivo que si se pueda reproducir de una lista proporcionada en tiempo de ejecución.

PD: De preferencia no usar jQuery.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí dejo un par de opciones hechas con JavaScript que cambian dependiendo de quién esté a cargo de la lógica para decidir qué fuente usar:

**Delegando la elección al navegador**

Como indica Leandro en su respuesta, una opción rápida sería añadir todas las fuentes dentro de la etiqueta `audio` y dejar que el navegador se encargue por sí mismo de seleccionar la primera que le funcione.

Así, si por ejemplo tienes una lista con las diferentes fuentes del audio podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
var sources = [
  {
    src: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg",
    type: "audio/ogg",
  },
  {
    src: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3",
    type: "audio/mp3",
  }
];

var miAudio = document.getElementById("miAudio");

for (var x = 0; x < sources.length; x++) {
  var src = document.createElement("source");
  src.src = sources[x].src;
  src.type = sources[x].type;
  miAudio.appendChild(src);
}
```

```html
<audio id="miAudio" controls></audio>
```

Ventajas de este método:

- Es simple y rápido.

Inconvenientes de este método:

- No sabes cuál de las fuentes se está escuchando.

---

**Lógica en el código**

Otra opción sería mantener tú el control en el código para saber cuál de las fuentes es la que realmente se está utilizando. En este caso, y suponiendo una lista de fuentes con la del ejemplo anterior, la solución sería así:

1. Seleccionar la primera fuente de la lista
2. Añadir la fuente como `src`
3. Si hubo un error al cargar la fuente:

   - Probar la siguiente fuente.
   - Volver al paso 2.

Entonces lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir un controlador para el evento `error` que se encargase de seleccionar la siguiente fuente en la lista y sustituir a la actual.

Un ejemplo de este código sería:

```js
var sources = [
  {
    src: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg",
    type: "audio/ogg",
  },
  {
    src: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3",
    type: "audio/mp3",
  }
];
var actual = 0;

var miAudio = document.getElementById("miAudio");
miAudio.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  console.log(sources[actual].src + " falló. Probando la siguiente fuente");
  actual++;
  miAudio.src = sources[actual].src;
});

miAudio.src = sources[actual].src;
```

```html
<audio id="miAudio" controls></audio>
```

Ventajas de este método:

- Control sobre la fuente que se está escuchando.

Inconvenientes de este método:

- Es un poco más complejo.

Comment: IE no soporta audio en ogg, así que puedes ver cómo cambia el resultado si ejecutas los códigos de arriba en Chrome e Internet Explorer (en IE se mostrará un mensaje en la consola en el segundo ejemplo)

Comment: Si de casualidad no soporta ninguno de los especificados da error no?

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que en lugar de asignar el src como atributo deberias asignarlo como un nuevo element "source"

```
var audioel = document.getElementById('audioElem');
var source= document.createElement('source');
source.type= 'audio/mp3';
source.src= 'audio/archivo.mp3';
audioel.appendChild(source);
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Mira este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lengua/qo47b26h/) para ver como switchear video (y precargarlos si deseas). Funciona igual para un elemento HTML5 de audio.